# shopware 6 can I run command forcefully(by coding)

Tags: command, shopware

I just want to run the command by code.
I mean how can run the "bin/console cache:clear" command by coding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it from "code" as it can be done from a terminal manually. E.g:

- `sudo rm -rf /var/www/shopware/var/cache/*`

In most cases that should probably be enough to trigger a cache regeneration in Shopware.

Doing this is sometimes necessary due to errors that prevent the `cache:clear` command from executing, and it appears that doing so will usually trigger regeneration of the cache.

It is not the exact same thing as `cache:clear` though, because the `cache:clear` command should also target stuff that is cached by something like Redis.

According to the official documentation, `cache:clear` will first create a new cache, and then delete the old one, after the new cache has been created. You don't get that with `rm -rf`, but the result should be very similar, because the cache is automatically created by Shopware.

The cache can also be cleared in the administration backend at `example.com/admin#/sw/settings/cache/index`

If you are using Redis for caching, you can clear the cache from terminal using:

- `redis-cli FLUSHDB` – clears currently selected redis DB
- `redis-cli FLUSHALL` – clears all the redis DBs

This can all be done with bash scripting.

It is recommended you run `cache:clear` once per day. E.g. Via cron.